# How to get 20 20 20 values from Arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist, pagination

I've 5000 data's in Arraylist..But, I want to get first 20 data while application launched.. At the End of Page , the application wants to get next 20 data.. It's a Pagination Application.. Anyone Help me to get Next .. Next data;s..

Comment: are you using recyclerview to display data?

Comment: S.. Recyclerview and Cardview..

Comment: are you fetching data from network or in memory?

Comment: Check out tutorials on endless recycler view. if you are ok using third party libraries, use this https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate

Comment: Ya.. I used rest api to get values.. I got all values and added in arraylist..

Comment: I'm using this library.. All r done.. But problem with List values..

Comment: Post your code and explain what is the problem

Comment: Bro Page Loading is not the Problem.. My questiion is i've 5000 datas in My arraylist.. How to get values from arraylist 1-20,21-40 like this..

Comment: Now I'm using Random to get random values from list..

Comment: keep a variable (```pagenumber```) and increment it every time . then do something like ```pagenumber*20``` this is start index. ```pagenumber*20+20``` for end of index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define `pageNumber` initially set to zero. This variable gets incremented every time you reach the end of recyclerview. Crate a method as below that would return you a subset of your master ArrayList

```
public List<User> foo(int pageNumber)
{
    return masterArrayList.subList(pageNumber * 20, pageNumber * 20 + 20);
}
```

Comment: Awesome rakesh.. It's working perfectly after modified small changes in my coding.. Thnaks man..

Comment: And Rakesh another one help.. I've some images link in that rest api link.. I got and stored those urls in arraylist.. but i can't able to get those images and show in Imageview.. Error shows like this.. "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null".. What should i do..

Comment: `private Bitmap getImage(String bitmapUrl){
        URL url;
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }

        return image;
    } ` This is my code to get images..

Comment: Let me help you with the safest and easiest way to add image to imageview... Use http://square.github.io/picasso/ ... all you have to do is write one line of code ```Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);```

Answer (score 1):

The webservice which you are calling modify that. return 20 values in a list, you just to send the index of the last loaded value, and web server should return you the next 20 of the list.

In Android recyclerview use onScroll listener to continue and call webservice in onScrollCompleted() method to set another 20 of the list.